# How to submit two apps as a bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I know there is some way to do this but cannot find out how - maybe I'm using the wrong search terms. I am trying to submit a bundle to the App Store which contains two of my apps at a discounted price. How do I do this please?

Comment: The term is [App Bundle](https://www.google.de/search?q=app+store+app+bundle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=4UJZWIOjFqWH8Qe7_ZWoCw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new bundle you just need to click on the "+" button on your apps page on itunesConnect, after that you can choose your apps, price, icon, etc.

[image]

You can read more about app bundles here:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/

And more specifically how to create bundle using iTunes Connect: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BundlingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH37-SW1